# Shell script to List all the files in a folder

Tags: shell-script

Please help me to write shell script to List all the files in a folder and Then change their permission to 777 if the file name starts with “C” and Delete the files that start with “F”

my code for above question is

```
for item in *
do
    if [ -f $item ]
    then
       echo $item
    fi 
    if [ $item  c* ]
    then
       chmod 777 -f c*
       echo $item
    fi
    if [ $item  f* ]
    then 
        rm -v f*
        echo $item
    fi
    
    
         
done
```

Kindly rectify

Comment: Unix&Linux.SE is not a "do my homework for me" service. Go to http://www.shellcheck.net and paste your script there. It will describe in detail any errors it finds. Hint: if you use a `for item in *` loop, don't use wildcards in `chmod` and `rm` commands inside the loop. Just see if the current `$item` satisfies the conditions and do the needful for it. The loop will set `$item` to each file in turn, so within the loop you only need to care about the current `$item` and leave the other files alone.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you, but this is the kind of thing that might suit a `case` construct - see [Using case statements](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)

Comment: In addition, you also want to double quote the variable `$item` in case any of the files have space(s). Also, what you have will list files, links, and subdirectories which probably isn't what you want unless you are absolutely certain that the directory contains files and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to solve your question. This is an answer about your question (which needs some formatting and more space than allowed in a comment).

1. If this is a homework assignment you should state that and you shouldn't ask about someone solving that for you, but you can ask specific questions in order to learn a bit more about Unix.
2. As it seems to be homework, the idea of the task probably was not about "having things done" but teach you about programming and thinking, so this is not the right channel for that questions.

3- What you can do here is, after you have broken down your problem in parts, ask about:

- How I list all the files?,
- How I search with a pattern?
- How I apply a command to files after filtering some of them?
- Do I want to use the shell commands to do that? or
- I will use bash as a programming language?

If your assignment was about programming with loops, case statements and if workflow and you have specific questions about it probably Stack Overflow is a better place.

If you are new to Linux and you don't know the commands yet or the magic of the pipes or how to use a shell script to automate these commands (this is plumbing not programming) is OK to ask about it, so you can learn about filtering with `grep` and execute with `xargs`, or filtering and execute with `find … -exec`.

For example in Linux you can list files with `ls` and filter with `grep` (here you need to look up which is the regular expression for 'starts with').

Once you know this, you need to decide if you want to put it in a loop or pipe to `xargs` (I recommend you learn the power of `xargs`).

This is a classical one-liner that will put you on the track:

```
ls | grep  "^c" | xargs -I{} echo "wanted_command -options command {}"
```

So you can write a script to automate that.

If this is an assignment, I would suggest you that you create a function for each action (you need to read about creating functions in shell) so you call the appropriate function in each `if`/`case` statement.